# Does this elevator door operator mechanism solely rely on the door weight when the timing belt opens the sword clutch?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have replicated the mechanism shown in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4J1ohfeAE9Y) as a miniature DIY project, but my replica slider that is supposed to carry the door later moves with little force by itself. If I attach a timing belt to it, the force required to move the slider is less than the force required to open the door swords (who act as a clutch for a passive shaft door), sliding open without properly engaging the swords in the correct position. In the video though the clutch fully opens before the door slider starts moving.

Is there a mechanism that I do not see in the video that causes the door slider to stay in position until the clutch is fully opened or do you think that this is simply achieved by the weight of the slider device?

Also can somebody explain the purpose of the long spring that is attached between the clutch swords?

Comment: This might benefit from a few diagrams of your design vs. the original, and any force calculations you've performed.